# Rails 6 call action if specific field changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 6 app I've got `User` model which has `first_name` and `last_name` fields. Both of these fields are required to create a new record. Now I want to trigger the `IdentityCheck.new(self).call` service each time when user updates his `first_name` or `last_name`.

Naturally I've tried something like below:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_update :restart_identity_check, if: :first_name_changed? || :last_name_changed?

  private

  def restart_identity_check
    IdentityCheck.new(self).call
  end
end
```

But I don't know why it won't worked. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

That's not the correct syntax for `if`.

```rb
after_update :restart_identity_check, if: Proc.new { |user| user.first_name_changed? || user.last_name_changed? }
```

You may wish to create an alternate method, like this:

```rb
after_update :restart_identity_check, if: :must_restart_identity_check?

# I'd make this private
private 

def must_restart_identity_check?
  first_name_changed? || last_name_changed?
end
```

Remember that `after_update` runs before record is commited to the database. So, if something happens in between, you are going to `restart_identity_check` even if your `User` changes is not commited to the database. I'd use `after_update_commit` just in case.